# ZF2 translator into controller

Tags: php, zend-framework2, translation, factory

I am trying to use the translator inside my application as showen below in my example but I am stuck with the error.

**module.config.php**

```
'controllers' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Application\Controller\AjaxController' => function($sm) {
               $translator = $sm->getServiceLocator()->get('translator');
               $controller = new Application\Controller\AjaxController($translator);
         }
  ),
```

**AjaxController.php**

```
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator;
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;
use Zend\Session\Container;
use Zend\Debug\Debug;

class AjaxController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $translator;

    public function __construct(Translator $translator)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }
```

**Error ouput**

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Application\Controller\AjaxController::__construct() 
must be an instance of Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator, instance of 
Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator given, called in 
*****/module/Application/config/module.config.php on line 515 and defined in 
*****/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/AjaxController.php on line 26
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message it seems that you are using the wrong translator. Try to change your use clause from `Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator` to `Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator`.

Comment: This results in:

Message:
The factory was called but did not return an instance.

Comment: @directory Add a `return $controller;` to your factory.